# R - skmeans with zeros

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm a total **R** beginner and try to cluster user data using the function skmeans.

I always get the error message:

> "Error in if (!all(row_norms(x) > 0)) stop("Zero rows are not allowed.") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".

There already is a topic about this error message explaining that zeros are not allowed in rows.

However, my blueprint for what I'm trying to do is an example based on a data set which is also full of zeros. Working with this example, the error message does not appear and the function works fine. The error message only occurs when I apply the same procedure to my data set which doesn't seem different from the blueprint's data set.

Here's the function used for the kmeans:

```
weindaten.clusters <- skmeans(wendaten.tr, 5, method="genetic")
```

And here's the data set:

[image: successful attempt]

For my own data set, I used this function

```
kunden.cluster<- skmeans(test4, 5, method="genetic")
```

for this data set:

[image: failed attempt]

Could somebody please help me understand what the difference between the two data sets is (vector vs. something else maybe) and how I can change my data to be able to use skeams?

Comment: Perhaps the first thing that you should do is to check if any row consists _entirely_ of zeros.  Try 
`which(rowSums( test4 == 0) == ncol(test4))`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. There are actually rows consisting entirely of zeros.

Comment: However, it seems that my data is “wrong” at some other point as well. I tried the function but it only returns “integer(0)”. I spotted the rows containing only zeros by viewing and ordering the data set. I’ll search for a way to get rid of all zero rows and start the cluster analysis again.

Comment: Good luck.  Getting rid of the zero rows may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use *spherical* k-means on this data.

Spherical k-means uses *angles* for similarity. But the all-zero row cannot be used in angular computations.

Choose a different algorithm, unless you can treat the all-zero roe specially (for example on text, this would be an empty document).